# Google maps/direction api - adding nearby places on the map?

Tags: html, navbar, bootstrap-4

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLQmqy

Above is a link to a nav-bar that I have been trying to create.

My Problem: I cant get my **ul** to show - About Destination Contact Login SignUp-

Can someone guide me to how to get that to show?

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Destinations</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you want to show a menu?

Comment: the snippet of code is just the portion I am having trouble with -sorry.
I do not - I just want those list items above, to be on the nav-bar between the "Final Destination" link and the 2 input-forms

Comment: ahh ok, so if you want to show on your map any nearly places, you can use the diferents api of google and render on markers or use the same render of some api places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below. This should get you your desired results. One thing that I'll point out is that you're targeting a beta version of Bootstrap 4. In the codepen below it targets version alpha.6.

Also, if you're using the `collapse` class, it's going hide the content in the element you use the class on. This is why your content wasn't being displayed. You can view the documentation for the collapse class [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/).

https://codepen.io/cowanjt/pen/dzQRyY

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded"  style="background-color:#e3f2fd">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Final Destination</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Destinations</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="origin" aria-label="Origin" id="shootOriginHere">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="destination" aria-label="Destination" id="shootDestinationHere">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much - honestly I went straight to bootstraps site and went to there documentation. I didn't even know there was an Alpha version haha